# Find duplicate entries

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with my program. I have entries in a sheet (*columns with name, gender,age,running distance of 5000 m, 3000 m, 2000 m, 1000 m and 500 m etc*). Each person(*for example say name x can participate in multiple events*).

I've parsed all the data from a raw data sheet to a clean sheet. I have to delete duplicate entries of swimmers participating in the clean sheet, but the problem is those are not actually duplicate entries but are multiple events participated by that (x) person. I have to

1. Check if the names of the next cell and current cell are equal(*say x has participated in event 5000m and 3000m, so his name comes twice in clean sheet*), and if equal
2. Take the corresponding values of the next cell(*3000m of the same name to the previous cell 3000m*), so after I delete the duplicate entries at last, x would have registered under 5000m cell and 3000 m cell.

Comment: i pasted it line by line, but the website is putting it in paragraphs. SORRY if it is not clear. Thanks

Comment: I'm trying to, but i cant. It says the code is not in format. how can I update it?

Comment: I cant paste it. Can I email You?

Comment: May I also see your excel File (Clean Sheet)?

Comment: Ok I have seen the workbook. Can you give me an example of a duplicate record?

Comment: i guess it should open a file for it. but siddarth I came up with a logic that would check at the beginning itself. So thank you very much for your patience , time and effort. Sorry to trouble you with this. thanks thanks

Answer (score 0):

try removing the duplicate by using VBA's built-in function "RemoveDuplicates"

```
Sheets("clean sheet").Range("<Your complete range>").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
```

It'll consider both columns and will remove only those entries, which are duplicate by considering both columns.

Comment: It still is'nt helping out kaushik.:(

Comment: but then my program gets back to the main sub every time and runs from there and check. It stops as soon as it sees a name to be duplicate of the previous one, then puts the corresponding cell event value to the previous cell. it does for the entire program and only then it should delete. will this command help for such a condition? it tried though, it is still the same

Comment: Try to record the macro for selecting your entire range, then go to Data section of excel, click on Remove Duplicates button. It'll ask for which columns you want to apply this chance. select appropriate columns -> press Ok. You'll see the code generated in the background. there you'll find the same command that I posted in my answer.

Comment: but i have another clarification. only the names are duplicates. i need to take the corresponding event distance value to the previous cells(for example, if the first duplicate name has 3000m to it on row 2, it should delete the entire 2nd row but the event distance of that row. that event should go one row up. it should loop for the entire sheet like the same. thanks

Comment: The names for which the second column is different will be retained. only the lines which are perfectly identical will be removed. so, if there are two distances for same name, both will be kept.